# C# Save File - (Delete and re-write?)

Tags: c#, file, save, delete-file

I am trying to create a save function in C#, which overwrites the existing file. I have the code -

```
public void savefile(string path)
{
  File.Delete(path);
  File.WriteAllText(path, "Hello World");
}
```

But there is always the possibility of the computer breaking, before the file has been saved/rewritten again, and I was wondering if there was a better way of doing it

Should I use a saveFileDialog, which is invisible to the user instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WriteAllText should be enough as it will overwrite the contents of your file.

```
public void savefile(string path)
{
  File.WriteAllText(path, "Hello World");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If the target file already exists, `WriteAllText` is overwrite it. So no need of two operations for your task.

```
public void savefile(string path)
{
  //File.Delete(path); you don't need this line
  File.WriteAllText(path, "Hello World");
}
```